# Django MANAGERS and ADMINS settings, do we need it configured?

Tags: django, django-settings

I know ADMINS can be used to receive error notifications on email

Something that can be better handled by datadog or sentry

For manager seems to be something even more specific, since you need t use  BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware as well

```
# MANAGER CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins
ADMINS = [
    ("Admin", "admin@mail.com"),
]

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#managers
MANAGERS = ADMINS
```

Does it have any other purpose?
Any reason to keep it on the Django settings?